# How to configure Flink to use Hdfs for backend state and checkpoints

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a setup with Flink v1.2, 3 JobManagers, 2 TaskManagers. I want to use hdfs for backend state and checkpoints and zookeeper storageDir

> state.backend: filesystem
>
> state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: hdfs:///[ip:port]/flink-checkpoints
>   state.checkpoints.dir: hdfs:///[ip:port]/external-checkpoints
>   high-availability: zookeeper
>   high-availability.zookeeper.storageDir:
>   hdfs:///[ip:port]/recovery

In the JobManager I log I have

```
2017-03-22 17:41:43,559 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: high-availability.zookeeper.client.acl, open
2017-03-22 17:41:43,680 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Error while starting up JobManager
java.io.IOException: The given HDFS file URI (hdfs:///ip:port/recovery/blob) did not describe the HDFS NameNode. The attempt to use a default HDFS configuration, as specified in the 'fs.hdfs.hdfsdefault' or 'fs.hdfs.hdfssite' config parameter failed due to the following problem: Either no default file system was registered, or the provided configuration contains no valid authority component (fs.default.name or fs.defaultFS) describing the (hdfs namenode) host and port.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.initialize(HadoopFileSystem.java:298)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:288)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:310)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.FileSystemBlobStore.<init>(FileSystemBlobStore.java:67)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer.<init>(BlobServer.java:114)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.createJobManagerComponents(JobManager.scala:2488)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.startJobManagerActors(JobManager.scala:2643)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.startJobManagerActors(JobManager.scala:2595)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.startActorSystemAndJobManagerActors(JobManager.scala:2242)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.liftedTree3$1(JobManager.scala:2020)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.runJobManager(JobManager.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:2098)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$2.apply(JobManager.scala:2076)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$2.apply(JobManager.scala:2076)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.retryOnBindException(JobManager.scala:2131)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.runJobManager(JobManager.scala:2076)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anon$9.call(JobManager.scala:1971)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anon$9.call(JobManager.scala:1969)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.main(JobManager.scala:1969)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.main(JobManager.scala)
2017-03-22 17:41:43,694 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation               - PriviledgedActionException as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: The given HDFS file URI (hdfs:///ip:port/recovery/blob) did not describe the HDFS NameNode. The attempt to use a default HDFS configuration, as specified in the 'fs.hdfs.hdfsdefault' or 'fs.hdfs.hdfssite' config parameter failed due to the following problem: Either no default file system was registered, or the provided configuration contains no valid authority component (fs.default.name or fs.defaultFS) describing the (hdfs namenode) host and port.
2017-03-22 17:41:43,694 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Failed to run JobManager.
java.io.IOException: The given HDFS file URI (hdfs:///ip:port/recovery/blob) did not describe the HDFS NameNode. The attempt to use a default HDFS configuration, as specified in the 'fs.hdfs.hdfsdefault' or 'fs.hdfs.hdfssite' config parameter failed due to the following problem: Either no default file system was registered, or the provided configuration contains no valid authority component (fs.default.name or fs.defaultFS) describing the (hdfs namenode) host and port.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.initialize(HadoopFileSystem.java:298)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:288)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:310)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.FileSystemBlobStore.<init>(FileSystemBlobStore.java:67)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer.<init>(BlobServer.java:114)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.createJobManagerComponents(JobManager.scala:2488)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.startJobManagerActors(JobManager.scala:2643)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.startJobManagerActors(JobManager.scala:2595)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.startActorSystemAndJobManagerActors(JobManager.scala:2242)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.liftedTree3$1(JobManager.scala:2020)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.runJobManager(JobManager.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:2098)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$2.apply(JobManager.scala:2076)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$2.apply(JobManager.scala:2076)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.retryOnBindException(JobManager.scala:2131)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.runJobManager(JobManager.scala:2076)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anon$9.call(JobManager.scala:1971)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anon$9.call(JobManager.scala:1969)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.main(JobManager.scala:1969)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.main(JobManager.scala)
2017-03-22 17:41:43,697 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Shutting down remote daemon.
2017-03-22 17:41:43,704 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
2
```

Hadoop is installed as a single node cluster on the VM which I set up in the settings. Why is Flink asking to configure extra parameters? (they are not in the official documentation btw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to use this URL pattern `hdfs://[ip:port]/flink-checkpoints` for accessing HDFS with hostname:port specification.

If you are using the `fs.defaultFS` from the Hadoop config, you don't need to put the NameNode details.